# On page refresh which life cycle method called in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have page which has componentA and on componentDidMount cycle method I am updating state which triggers some animation. But if I refresh the page, the animation doesn't play. Please let me know how I can resolve this issue. Below is my component code.

```
import React from 'react';
import { findDOMNode } from 'react-dom';
import Nav from "../nav/nav-component";
class Mylist extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleScroll = this.handleScroll.bind(this);
    this.state = { animationClass: '' , transform : 12  };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
      window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
      this.setState({animationClass:'animate'});
  };
  componentDidUpdate() {
      //this.setState({animationClass:''});
  };

  componentWillUnmount() {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
      this.setState({animationClass:''});
  };
  handleScroll(event){
    const scrollTop = event.srcElement.body.scrollTop,
          ele = findDOMNode(this.refs.toggle), // how to get dom element in react
          childElements = ele.children,
          componentTopPos = ele.getBoundingClientRect();
    //itemTranslate = Math.min(0, scrollTop/3 - 60);

    console.log("scrollTop",scrollTop);
    console.log(childElements);
    console.log("componentTopPos",componentTopPos);

     console.log(this);
    this.setState({
      transform: "dsfdf"
    });
  }
  render(){
    return ( 
      <div className={'header '+this.state.animationClass}>
      <Nav />
      </div> 
    );
  }
}
export default Mylist;
```

Comment: Does the page not scroll at all, or does it jump to the target position without animating? Perhaps it is running too early and the page content doesn't have a height yet or something?

Comment: I'm also looking for that answer, anyone?

Comment: componentDIdMount is called once, componentWillUpdate has been deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Bear in mind that componentDidMount is called only once. It doesn't matter how many times you will refresh the page. The method is not going to be called again. Better way to play the animation in my opinion is to set a flag in your local state, for instance "playAnimation: true", after the animation is played set your state to false. On refresh your state is going to become true again and the animation will play again. Hope I helped.